# How can I change parent control's content though child control event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three user controls. ControlC is parent of ControlB, ControlB is parent of ControlA.Now I wan to use a ControlA's event to change ControlC's content(let's say change ControlC's content to ControlD). I can do this if there are only 2 Controls, I don't know to do it with 3 Controls. Any idea with it?
For 2 controls solution is:

```
        private void ChangeParentContent()
    {
        UserControlB userControlB = (UserControlB)this.Parent;
        userControlB.Content = new userControlC();
    }
```

Comment: Controls shouldn't know about how they're used in such a way.  If the parent control wants to make a change in response to an event *they* should be the ones adding the event handler and writing the code to do so, not the child control.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question a couple of times, I think I better understand what you're going for.  @Servy is correct, you should not modify the parent from the child.  Instead, create events that the parents can subscribe to.  When the event is fired you can handle the event in the parent.  My original answer (below) provides for a couple of paths you could use to achieve this.

**ORIGINAL**

A couple of ideas:

1. ControlB could subscribe to the ControlA event.  ControlB then fires its own event, to which ControlC is subscribed.
2. Change the `Modifier` of ControlA to `public` so that you can access it directly from ControlC (`ControlB.ControlA.Event += ...`)

Comment: Yup, the cleanest way to let change propagate between components is via events. Getting used to event propagation makes it easier to move to other GUI frameworks as well.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should firstly create a event in parent control and then invoke it in child control. If I am right, how can I invoke this event in child control? Initialize parent A and call it? Could you provide some code example? Much appreciate.

Comment: @CZA You have that backwards.  The child should not be subscribing to the events of the parent.  They shouldn't know anything about their parents.  The parent should subscribe to an even of the child if they want to do something in response to something happening to the child, as is the case in your example.